# RGraph not displaying anything?

Tags: javascript, html, graph

I'm simply trying to generate a chart using RGraph so that I can begin using SQL to manipulate the graph. However, the issue i'm having is that it isn't showing the basic graph at all. Anyone know where i'm going wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Charts</title>
<script src="JAVASCRIPT/RGraph.common.core.js"></script>
<script src="JAVASCRIPT/RGraph.bar.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="cvs1" width="600" height="250">[No canvas support]</canvas>
<script>
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        var bar = new RGraph.Bar({
            id:'cvs1',
            data: [4,5,3,8,4,9,6,5,3],
            options: {
                backgroundGridDashed: true,
                labels: ['Mal', 'Barry', 'Gary', 'Neil', 'Kim', 'Pete', 'Lou', 'Fred', 'Jobe'],
                title: 'A dashed background grid',
                strokestyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                textAccessible: true
            }
        }).draw();
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Browser Error**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
>
> RGraph.Bar    @   RGraph.bar.js:28
>
> window.onload @   Charts.php:17

Comment: did you check your browser console for any js errors ?

Comment: I've just added the error that i'm getting to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code. Nothing wrong with it, but it seems to be very dependent on which version of RGraph you're using. Try downloading [the latest version of RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/download) and extracting the contents (or just the two files you need) under 'libraries' to your 'JAVASCRIPT' folder.

Comment: This has worked I simply updated the files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem! Have fun with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some updated code (a few property names have changed since this was asked).

```
bar = new RGraph.Bar({
     id:'cvs1',
     data: [4,5,3,8,4,9,6,5,3],
     options: {
         backgroundGridDashed: true,
         xaxisLabels: ['Mal', 'Barry', 'Gary', 'Neil', 'Kim', 'Pete', 'Lou', 'Fred', 'Jobe'],
         title: 'A dashed background grid',
         colorsStroke: 'transparent'
         // textAccessible: true // Defaults to true anyway
     }
 }).draw();
```